# nextjs 13: disable cache in serverless functions

Tags: caching, next.js, serverless

I have a nextjs app using nextjs 13 with the app router. One endpoint returns a randomInt:

```
import { randomInt } from "crypto";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET() {
  return NextResponse.json({ revenue: randomInt(100) });
}
```

In local, every time I load this endpoint, I get a different number. But when in prod on vercel I always get the same number like if it was cached. How can I disable it?

Comment: For fetch requests, you can just add `next: { revalidate: 0 }` to the fetch options object.  Have you tried setting: `export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';`?  Details [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#opting-out-of-data-caching).

Comment: Thanks but I don't think it's an issue on the fetch side because I get cached results on the results on the api endpoint directly (even through a different browser). I guess it's server side caching. I will try the dynamic config option

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is indeed the cache, you can try using the fetch function parameters. Something like:

```
fetch("[path]", {
 method: "GET",
 cache: "no-store",
})
```

There are some other arguments and options to look for, just look on their website or in the “RequestInit” interface.
Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/fetch.

Comment: Thank you unfortunately this didn't help. It seems to be a server side caching of the  serverless responses.

Answer (score 0):

I too tried disabling the cache as mentioned on their documentation. However, it didn't work

1. Time based revalidation :

   ```
   const data:Response = await fetch(`/api/gettasks?_cache=${Date.now()}`, {next: {revalidate: 10}});
   ```
2. On-Demand revalidation :

   ```
   const data:Response = await fetch(`/api/gettasks?_cache=${Date.now()}`, {next: { tags: ['blog']}});
   ```
3. On the server ( api/gettasks/route.ts), I tried to disable the cache by using revalidateTag method.

   ```
      export async function GET(request: NextRequest, response: NextResponse) {

   let data = await getTasks();
   revalidateTag('blog');
   return NextResponse.json({revalidated: true, body: data});
     }
   ```
4. But still the request were having the same `x-Vercel-Cache: HIT` instead of `x-Vercel-Cache: MISS`
5. A similar issue has already been reported to them , and it is currently in open state for more than a year.

> https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/42112

Answer (score 0):

When opening the API endpoint like https://mysite.vercel.app/api/GetData shows same data even when data is supposed to get updated, you can add the following line at the end of api route file.

```
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
```